# Increase of Cryptocurrency wallet number makes all of them not work

Tags: wallet

I have fifteen Cryptocurrency Wallets constantly running on one of my computers, Everything worked well, recently I added few more coins and all wallets have got synchronization issues (not syncing). I shut down several of them and things got working again. I tested that it is wallet independent problem, closing any of them solves problem, but I have to run all wallets constantly.

I am using windows 7, 64 bit, RAM 8 gb, only 50% of Ram and 10% of CPU is used in average. My Internet speed: 4 Mb Download, 0.25 Upload. My traffic (checked by freemeter) ~ 0.2 Mb Download 0.05 Mb Upload.

Can someone suggest what might be a problem?

Comment: This sounds very much like you already know the answer to your question. Its an issue of bandwidth, there are a few things you can try to do to reduce the load first thing I would suggest is reduce your -maxconnections= on each client, it will reduce their overall footprint.

Comment: you can allso adjust  -blockminsize=<n>      Set minimum block size in bytes (default: 0)
 -blockmaxsize=<n>      Set maximum block size in bytes (default: 250000)
 -blockprioritysize=<n> Set maximum size of high-priority/low-fee transactions in bytes (default: 27000)
 -mintxfee=<m.n>        Minimum  fee-per-kilobyte to qualify as fee-paying (default: 0.0001)  these will effect what transactions your client will and will not relay based on their size and the fee value.  This can also help reduce unnecessary network load.

Answer (score 0):

Many clients running at once will of course take up a lot CPU and RAM. Syncing is a CPU/RAM intensive task as well. Consider running one at a time?